# Multiple drop down not working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I tried to create a multiple drop down here is the HTML , JS code

```
<div class="meaaow">
<select style="margin-top:10px;width: 90%;margin-left:5px;" name="3223|887" id="3223" class="pp ProjectType_1" required="" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]">
    <option value="0" selected="">Requirements</option>
    <option value="Services">Services</option>
    <option value="Products" selected="">Products</option>
</select>

<select style="margin-bottom:10px;width: 90%;margin-left:5px;" name="3224|888" id="3224" class="qq SubProjectType_1" required="" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
</select>

<select style="margin-bottom:10px;width: 90%;margin-left:5px;" name="3387|947" id="3387" class="SubsubProjectType_1" required="" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]">
    <option value="0">Select Sub Category</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**JS**

Complete Js on the link

[**FIDDLELINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/8819/)

So what I am trying to do is

```
$('.pp').change(function () {
    var classNamex = $(this).attr('class');
    var pTypeBufr = classNamex.split(' ');
    var ptype = pTypeBufr[1].split('_');
    var OptIndex = $('option:selected', $(this)).index();
    var optionx = "<option value=''>Select Category</option>";


    //alert(OptIndex);
    if(OptIndex !=4)
    {
        var SubProject_arr = s_a[OptIndex].split("|");
        for (var i = 0; i < SubProject_arr.length; i++) {

            optionx += "<option value='" + SubProject_arr[i] + "' >" + SubProject_arr[i] + "</option>";
        }
    }
    if(OptIndex ==1)
    $('.SubProjectType_'+ptype[1]).removeClass('qq').addClass('uu').html(optionx);
    if(OptIndex ==2)
    $('.SubProjectType_'+ptype[1]).removeClass('uu').addClass('qq').html(optionx);
});
```

and for two different classes I have two function like this

```
$('.qq').change(function () {
        var classNamex = $(this).attr('class');
        var pTypeBufr = classNamex.split(' ');
        var ptype = pTypeBufr[1].split('_');
        var OptIndex = $('option:selected', $(this)).index();
        var optionx = "<option value=''>Select Sub Category</option>";


        alert('sssss');
        if(OptIndex ==2)
        {
            var SubProject_arr = t_a[OptIndex].split("|");
            for (var i = 0; i < SubProject_arr.length; i++) {

                optionx += "<option value='" + SubProject_arr[i] + "' >" + SubProject_arr[i] + "</option>";
            }
        }
       // alert('.SubProjectType_'+ptype[1]);
        $('.SubsubProjectType_'+ptype[1]).html(optionx);
    });
```

and for class .uu

```
$('.uu').change(function () {

    var classNamex = $(this).attr('class');
    var pTypeBufr = classNamex.split(' ');
    var ptype = pTypeBufr[1].split('_');
    var OptIndex = $('option:selected', $(this)).index();
    var optionx = "<option value=''>Select Sub Category</option>";


    alert('im inside uu');

        var SubProject_arr = u_a[OptIndex].split("|");
        for (var i = 0; i < SubProject_arr.length; i++) {

            optionx += "<option value='" + SubProject_arr[i] + "' >" + SubProject_arr[i] + "</option>";
        }

   // alert('.SubProjectType_'+ptype[1]);
    $('.SubsubProjectType_'+ptype[1]).html(optionx);
});
```

SO basically I am updating the class name of the 2nd drop down , But every time I use 2nd drop down always the function related with `.qq` class is only firing

Please help me

Comment: Could you be clearer in explaining what you're trying to do?

Comment: what is the error ? I just go through the fiddle example, but it seems working

Comment: @RyanLittle I am trying to update the 3rd drop down based on the value of 2nd drop down , So when I select Product, Services , I update the class of 2nd drop down either qq or uu , And I have two different function for both the classes which will update the 3rd drop down using two different arrays , 

My problem is only function related with qq class is working bot the uu class

Comment: here no need to dealing with class, just use id , u have 3 dropdowns do in first dropdownlists onchange event you can load second one, and based on second dropdownlists onchange event you can load thired on ,if u want both 1 st and 2 nd dropdown list values for loading 3 rd dropdown then in second dropdown's onchange take 1 st and s2nd dropdown selected values and based on that load 3 rd one

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I have 5 of those 3 set of drop downs in my web page

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV please use the Fiddle maybe you can implement your changes

Comment: Your code is too complicated, however I have forked the fiddle and made new one [http://jsfiddle.net/7o57gb9h/] , seems this is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find class `uu` in original HTML, And I see you dynamically toggle class `uu` and `qq`.

Use event-delegation for events on dynamic content :

```
     $(document).on('change', '.pp', function () { .....
     $(document).on('change', '.qq', function () { .....
     $(document).on('change', '.uu', function () { .....
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for . Sorry I was unclear with my explanation , I am gonna try this and accept your answer